# How do I get past IndentationError with try and except in a for loop?

Tags: python

```
given_items = ["one", "two", 3, 4, "five", ["six", "seven", "eight"]]
for item in given_items:
    try:
        for element in item:

    except TypeError:
            pass
    else:
        print(element)
```

prints:

```
o
n
e
t
w
o
```

(Vertically)

Then line 6 (for element in item) crashes the program with a gives a `IndentationError: expected an indented block` on reaching 3 in the list.

The object of the program is catch items that cannot be iterated and print the rest.  How do I get past this error?

Comment: `for element in item:` needs some code in that block. Even a `pass` will prevent the indention error.

Comment: put `print(element)` inside `for element in item:`, not in `else`

Comment: This is close and gives me something to work on.  The output was o e o eight.

Comment: That code doesn't produce that output, it errors straight away. You need to provide a [mre]. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `print()` inside inner `for`-loop

```
given_items = ["one", "two", 3, 4, "five", ["six", "seven", "eight"]]
for item in given_items:
    try:
        for element in item:
            print(element)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

But it will print also elements form list `["six", "seven", "eight"]` so you get

```
o
n
e
t
w
o
f
i
v
e
six
seven
eight
```

If you want to skip element from list then you should rather check type of data

```
given_items = ["one", "two", 3, 4, "five", ["six", "seven", "eight"]]
for item in given_items:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        for element in item:
            print(element)
```

and it will give only

```
o
n
e
t
w
o
f
i
v
e
```

But if you want to display `six`, `seven`, `eight` like other strings - one char in line - then you may need recursion

```
given_items = ["one", "two", 3, 4, "five", ["six", "seven", "eight"]]

def display(data):
    for item in data:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            for element in item:
                print(element)
        if isinstance(item, list):
            display(item) # recursion 

display(given_items)
```

Result

```
o
n
e
t
w
o
f
i
v
e
s
i
x
s
e
v
e
n
e
i
g
h
t
```

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for.  This site and the people on it are amazing.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: to upvote you should have arrows (triangles) above and below number `0` on the left side of my answer. To mark as accepted you should have option after few minutes but I don't know in which place - I never created any question so I didn't have to mark any answer as accepted

Comment: Apparently, I haven't earned a 15 reputation to be able to do the upvote.  I did click the check mark and will come back to the upvote when I reach the 15 level.  Thanks again for the help.